# HTML - Title attribute not showing up (Internet Explorer)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In Internet Explorer the title attribute of the image is not showing up. If works in Firefox and Chrome. I have looked at other posts but cannot get my head around it, I'm talking about this:

```
<html>
    <i><strong><a href="__URL__" target="_blank">PDW Status: </a></strong></i>
    <a href="__URL__" target="_blank"></a>
    <a href="__URL__" target="_blank"><br/></a>

    <a href="__URL__" target="_blank">Green</a>&#160;-
    <img id="Green" class="ms-rtePosition-4 ms-rteImage-2 ms-rteStyle-Emphasis" alt="lightgreen1.jpg"
    src="__URL__" style="margin: 5px;"/></em>&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;

    <a href="__URL__" target="_blank">Red</a>&#160;-  
    <img id="Red" class="ms-rtePosition-4 ms-rteImage-2 ms-rteStyle-Emphasis" alt="red1.jpg"
    src="__URL__" style="margin: 5px;"/></em>&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;

    <a href="__URL__" target="_blank">Yellow</a>&#160;- 
    <img id="Yellow" class="ms-rtePosition-4 ms-rteImage-2 ms-rteStyle-Emphasis" alt="yellow1.jpg"
    src="__URL__" style="margin: 5px;"/>&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;

    <a href="__URL__" target="_blank">White</a> &#160;-
    <img id="White" class="ms-rteImage-2 ms-rtePosition-4" alt="white.jpg"
    src="__URL__" style="margin: 5px;"/>&#160;

</html>

<style>
    a:link { text-decoration: none;
    color: #0072c6 } a:visited { text-decoration: none; color: #0072c6 } a:hover { text-decoration: underline;  } a:active { text-decoration: underline; }
</style>​

<script type="text/javascript">
//Grab data from list and post into HTML Fields
$(function() {
    green = "";
    yellow = "";
    red = "";
    white = "";

    $.ajax({
            url: "__URL__",
            headers: {"Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"}, 
            type: "GET", 
            cache: false,
            async: false,      

        }).success(function (data) {
            $.each(data.d.results, function(key, value) {
                 console.log(value.Title);
                 switch (value.Title) {
                    case "GREEN":
                        green += value.Description;
                        console.log("GREEN TEST" + green);
                        var gDescription = document.querySelector('#Green');
                        gDescription.title = "" + green;    
                        break;
                    case "YELLOW":
                        yellow += value.Description;
                        console.log("YELLOW TEST" + yellow);
                        var yDescription = document.querySelector('#Yellow');
                        yDescription.title = "" + yellow;   
                        break;
                    case "RED":
                        red += value.Description;
                        console.log("RED TEST" + red);
                        var rDescription = document.querySelector('#Red');
                        rDescription.title = "" + red;
                        break;
                    default:
                        white += value.Description;
                        console.log("WHITE TEST" + white);
                        var wDescription = document.querySelector('#White');
                        wDescription.title = "" + white;
                }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Related questions: [Html title attribute showing up in-flow, inside element, when howering over it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10472471/html-title-attribute-showing-up-in-flow-inside-element-when-howering-over-it)

Comment: @freefaller Sorry I removed those I will readd them but that is not the issue.

Comment: Is that your actual code? Because the `style` and `script` elements should be inside `html` and you are missing a `body` element...

Comment: Also which version(s) of IE have you tried? It seems the behavior changed in IE8 https://robertnyman.com/2009/05/07/the-alt-attribute-is-not-for-tooltips/ I'm also curious what happens if you add a `title="whatever"` attribute to the `img` tags. Does IE continue to not show any title, or does it show "whatever" instead of the new title set by javascript? (in other words is it not recognizing that the title changed)

Comment: @CodingWithSpike I'm on IE11. Also that was not my complete actual code. My actual code has the style and script and body all right. I did add the title="whatever" and the attribute is shown then. Very interesting.